# change background color of JButton

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jbutton

When I click the button, I hope the background of the JButton will change its color. When I try to compile, an error appears

> class, interface, or enum expected

Anyone can help me to figure out what's the problem?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    count ++;
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    boolean BlackTurn = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            if(b == gameBoard[i][j] && gameBoard[i][j].getBackground() == Color.green) {
                gameBoard[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  That makes it difficult to help.

Comment: What line is the compile time error thrown on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably a problem of **missing curly bracket** or **missing semicolon**:
the error message you get refers to some **missing** (understand *incorrect*) `class` (or `interface`, or `enum`) declaration.

If you were to post the whole content of the class declaration enclosing that method you showed us, I'm pretty sure we could find that missing character in a matter of seconds ;)

---

Also, since I'm at it, I prefer to use `Color.GREEN` (and `Color.BLACK`, `Color.RED`, etc.) instead of `Color.green`, because *these aliases respect the convention that states that **constants must be upper-case***.